# how to send values to Alarm manager in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-calendar

In my application i need to send the dynamic  values to  alarm manager.

when i send static values to the alarm manager it is working fine.  Please any one help me out. Thank you in advance.

my code:
  DatabaseHandler.java:

```
    public void add_mobilenotification(int year, int month,int date, int hour, int min ,int sec ){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(YEAR, year);
            values.put(MONTH, month);
            values.put(DATE, date);

            values.put(HOUR, hour );
            values.put(MIN, min);
            values.put(SEC, sec);
            db.insert(TABLE_MOBILENOTIFICATIONS, null, values);

         }

 public void set_datemonth(int month){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String opQryString = "SELECT " + DATE + "," + MONTH + "," + YEAR + ",+ HOUR + ",+ MIN + ",+ SEC + " FROM " + TABLE_MOBILENOTIFICATIONS + " WHERE "  + MONTH + "= '" + month+ "'";
        Cursor getmonthdateType = db.rawQuery(opQryString, null);
        if (getmonthdateType.moveToFirst()) {
            dt = getmonthdateType.getInt(0);
            mnth= getmonthdateType.getInt(1);
         yr= getmonthdateType.getInt(2);
          hr= getmonthdateType.getInt(3);
          min = getmonthdateType.getInt(4);
     sec = getmonthdateType.getInt(5);


        }
    }
```

Activity:

```
 db = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
         db.add_mobilenotification(2015,2,9,13,40,2);
         db.set_datemonth(9);
          private void initAlarm(){

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SplashActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,db.mnth);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,db.yr);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,db.dt);

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,db.hr);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,db.min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,db.sec);



                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }
```

Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".activity.MyAlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".activity.MyReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Intialize the Local Variable with Dynamic Value just Simple and also post where is your code for db using that you are fetching the dynamic value

Comment: @Rajan i done like that also. local variables are also intialized with db values. but not working

Comment: it´s not clear enough, do You have a problem with passing data via intent or do You have a problem with getting Your data from database? I assume You have time stored in a database and want to pass it to AlarmManager like You did it with cal.set....am I right?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes, i checked that the values are coming from db properly.

Comment: yes, cal.set i am using

Comment: Then this question needs more information. Is this a static database which never changes the entries? Or is it a usual database where user puts some information inside? I think You have to be more clear what Your goal is and You should provide some piece of code how You get the data from Your database...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs please see edited post

Comment: `(I need to send the dynamic values from database.)` i am pretty sure nobody knows what you mean by saying `dynamic values`

Comment: ok, now I think I got it. And please, noe explain what EXACTLY is going wrong. Is the alarmmanager not firing, or too late, or everytime at the same time although You set another time.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs. not firing. what i done wrong. i just pass the values from data base only

Comment: have You registered Your BroadcastReceiver in Your Manifest?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes. edited in post

Comment: there are a few other possible issues. First, be sure the query works correct, make a Log to see if it works. next thing, check exactly the time you set to calendar because, for example, January starts with number 0, not 1 like some poeple would assume. February is 1 ...and so on. AND HOUR_OF_DAY is for 24 hour, if You use only 12 hour, then You have to use HOUR.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs will check again properly. will get back to you. thank you for your Reply

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your problem. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem is that the alarmManager is not firing....but where the issue comes from is unclear.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs thank you very much. I resolved the issue with your comment. yes i took feb as 2 and calling that alaram manager method before the insertion. Thanks again

Comment: @Opiatefuchs my alarm firing even when the time was past. could you please help me.

Comment: is the alarm fired two times?

Answer (score 0):

I did this kind of work with alarm following [this](https://github.com/steventrigg/AlarmClock) repository in github. Mainly in this project the data like time, date, day etc are given as input in the database. We maintain a model class and get data from database according to the model. Then we set our alarm . For setting the alarm we use a AlarmHelper class that extends a BroadcastListener. It given below

```
public class AlarmManagerHelper extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String TIME_HOUR = "timeHour";
public static final String TIME_MINUTE = "timeMinute";
public static final String TONE = "alarmTone";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    setAlarms(context);
}

public static void setAlarms(Context context) {
    cancelAlarms(context);

    AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);

    List<AlarmModel> alarms =  dbHelper.getAlarms();

    for (AlarmModel alarm : alarms) {
        if (alarm.isEnabled) {

            PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context, alarm);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.timeHour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.timeMinute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            //Find next time to set
            final int nowDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            final int nowHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            final int nowMinute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            boolean alarmSet = false;

            //First check if it's later in the week
            for (int dayOfWeek = Calendar.SUNDAY; dayOfWeek <= Calendar.SATURDAY; ++dayOfWeek) {
                if (alarm.getRepeatingDay(dayOfWeek - 1) && dayOfWeek >= nowDay &&
                        !(dayOfWeek == nowDay && alarm.timeHour < nowHour) &&
                        !(dayOfWeek == nowDay && alarm.timeHour == nowHour && alarm.timeMinute <= nowMinute)) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

                    setAlarm(context, calendar, pIntent);
                    alarmSet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Else check if it's earlier in the week
            if (!alarmSet) {
                for (int dayOfWeek = Calendar.SUNDAY; dayOfWeek <= Calendar.SATURDAY; ++dayOfWeek) {
                    if (alarm.getRepeatingDay(dayOfWeek - 1) && dayOfWeek <= nowDay && alarm.repeatWeekly) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
                        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

                        setAlarm(context, calendar, pIntent);
                        alarmSet = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private static void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, PendingIntent pIntent) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    }
}

public static void cancelAlarms(Context context) {
    AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);

    List<AlarmModel> alarms =  dbHelper.getAlarms();

    if (alarms != null) {
        for (AlarmModel alarm : alarms) {
            if (alarm.isEnabled) {
                PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context, alarm);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context, AlarmModel model) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    intent.putExtra(ID, model.id);
    intent.putExtra(NAME, model.name);
    intent.putExtra(TIME_HOUR, model.timeHour);
    intent.putExtra(TIME_MINUTE, model.timeMinute);
    intent.putExtra(TONE, model.alarmTone.toString());

    return PendingIntent.getService(context, (int) model.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
}
```

But i will recommend you to go through the repository to understand the whole thing in a better way

Answer (score -1):

add data to intent. `intent.putExtra("key",data);`, then retrieve it in BroadcastReceiver like this: `String data = intent.getStringExtra("key");`

Comment: This step is obvious and people have added this, even after that it is not working.